# dockerbuildしたいです

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

下記のサイトを参考にdocker build .をしたいのですがうまくいきません
https://engineering.adwerx.com/rails-on-kubernetes-8cd4940eacbe

最初は
app.conf 
config.ru 
Dockerfile 
env.conf 
Gemfile 
Gemfile.lock 
Rakefile 
を作り、`docker build .`を実行したところ下記エラーが出ました。

```
rake aborted! Do not know how to build task 'assets: precompile'
　(See full trace by running task with - trace) The command '/ bin / sh -c bundle 　exec rake ass

ets: precompile' returned a non-zero code: 1 I got an error　saying.
```

次に
https://github.com/jbielick/rails-kube-demo を`git clone`したのですが
下記エラーがでました。

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/puma-3.6.0/ext/puma_http11
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.8/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20190109-5-1ymcdr3.rb
extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
creating Makefile
current directory:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/puma-3.6.0/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory:
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/puma-3.6.0/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
In file included from ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:7:0:
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl: In function ‘puma_parser_execute’:
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:111:17: warning: comparison between signed and
unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:37:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:39:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:52:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:54:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:37:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:39:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:55:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:57:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:37:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:39:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:244:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:246:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:251:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:253:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:258:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:260:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:265:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:267:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:272:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:274:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:281:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:283:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:288:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:290:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:49:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:51:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:325:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:327:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:353:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:355:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:41:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:43:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:46:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:48:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:46:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:48:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:55:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:57:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:37:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:39:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:37:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:39:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:37:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:39:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:37:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:39:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:71:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:73:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:71:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:73:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:60:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:62:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:653:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:655:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:671:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:673:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:689:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:691:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:707:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:709:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:725:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:727:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:743:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:745:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:761:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:763:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:779:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:781:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:797:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:799:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:815:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:817:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:833:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:835:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:851:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:853:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:869:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:871:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:887:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:889:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:905:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:907:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:923:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:925:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:941:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:943:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:959:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:961:1: note: here
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:977:5: warning: this statement may fall through
[-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:979:1: note: here
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
mini_ssl.c: In function ‘get_dh1024’:
mini_ssl.c:90:5: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘DH {aka struct
dh_st}’
   dh->p = BN_bin2bn(dh1024_p, sizeof(dh1024_p), NULL);
     ^~
mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_init_server’:
mini_ssl.c:139:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
[-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   ID sym_cert = rb_intern("cert");
   ^~
mini_ssl.c:144:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
[-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   ID sym_ca = rb_intern("ca");
   ^~
mini_ssl.c:166:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
[-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   DH *dh = get_dh1024();
   ^~
mini_ssl.c:170:3: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
[-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
   EC_KEY *ecdh = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp521r1);
   ^~~~~~
mini_ssl.c: In function ‘engine_init_client’:
mini_ssl.c:197:3: warning: ‘DTLSv1_method’ is deprecated
[-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   conn->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLSv1_method());
   ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/ct.h:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:61,
                 from mini_ssl.c:15:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1642:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.0 */
 ^
Makefile:238: recipe for target 'mini_ssl.o' failed
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1
make failed, exit code 2
Gem files will remain installed in
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/gems/puma-3.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.8/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/puma-3.6.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing puma (3.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '3.6.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.
In Gemfile:
  puma
The command '/bin/sh -c bundle install' returned a non-zero code: 5
```

Answer (score 3):

最終的に以下のようにするとbuildできました。

ref: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1136

1. Dockerfile以下のように修正

   23行目: `curl libssl-dev \` -> `curl libssl1.0-dev \`

   **Dockerfile**

   ```
   FROM phusion/passenger-ruby23

   # set some rails env vars
   ENV RAILS_ENV production
   ENV BUNDLE_PATH /bundle

   # set the app directory var
   ENV APP_HOME /home/app
   WORKDIR $APP_HOME

   # Enable nginx/passenger
   RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

   # Disable SSH
   # Some discussion on this: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7950326
   RUN rm -rf /etc/service/sshd /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh

   RUN apt-get update -qq

   # Install apt dependencies
   RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
     build-essential \
     curl libssl1.0-dev \
     git \
     unzip \
     zlib1g-dev \
     libxslt-dev \
     mysql-client \
     sqlite3

   # install bundler
   RUN gem install bundler

   # Separate task from `add . .` as it will be
   # Skipped if gemfile.lock hasn't changed
   COPY Gemfile* ./

   # Install gems to /bundle
   RUN bundle install

   # place the nginx / passenger config
   RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
   ADD nginx/env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/env.conf
   ADD nginx/app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app.conf

   ADD . .

   # compile assets!
   RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

   EXPOSE 3000

   CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
   ```
2. `Gemfile.lock`を削除
3. Gemfile以下のように修正
   48行目: `gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]` -> `gem 'tzinfo-data'`

   ```ruby
   source 'https://rubygems.org'


   # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
   gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
   # Use mysql as the database for Active Record
   gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.3.18', '< 0.5'
   # Use Puma as the app server
   gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
   # Use SCSS for stylesheets
   gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
   # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
   # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
   # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
   # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

   # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
   gem 'jquery-rails'
   # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
   gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
   # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
   gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
   # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
   # gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
   # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
   # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

   # Use Capistrano for deployment
   # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

   group :development, :test do
     # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
     gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
   end

   group :development do
     # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
     gem 'web-console'
     gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
     # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
     gem 'spring'
     gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
   end

   # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
   gem 'tzinfo-data'
   ```

２年前のもので依存パッケージのverが変わってしまい、エラーが起きていましたね…
２年となるともう古いので、なるべく新し目のチュートリアルをお勧めします。

Comment: 本当にありがとうございます。
試してみたいと思います。
新し目のチュートリアルも探してみます